# Trying to solve a functional equation

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, analysis, derivatives

Let $a_n$ be a sequence of strictly positive real numbers such that $\lim_{n \to \infty}a_n=0$. Find all functions $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ that admit primitives(i.e. there exists a function $F:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $\frac{dF(x)}{dx}=f(x), \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$) and satisfies the following equality $$2f(x)=f(x+a_n)+f(x-a_n), \forall x \in \mathbb{R}, \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$$
My approach to this problem was to first use the fact that there exists a function $F:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, such that $F'(x)=f(x)$, so the equation becomes $2F(x)=F(x+a_n)+F(x-a_n)+C_n$, for some arbitrary constant $C_n$. Rearranging the terms, we get that $$0=\frac{F(x+a_n)-F(x)}{a_n}-\frac{F(x-a_n)-F(x)}{-a_n} + \frac{C_n}{a_n}$$
Because $a_n$ approaches $0$ we can take the limit as $n$ approaches $\infty$, and because $F$ is differentiable, we obtain $0=\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{C_n}{a_n}$. Therefore $\lim_{n \to \infty}C_n=0$, but that is not useful. $f(x)=0$,$f(x)=k, F(x)=kx$ satisfy the equation, but I  cannot seem to deduce them. Did I do a mistake or is the exercise wrong?

Comment: There must be a mistake somewhere, since the function $f=0$ satisfies the conclusion.

Comment: $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{C}{a_n}$ is $0$ if $C = 0$.

Comment: Oh I see, the $\frac{F(x−a_n)−F(x)}{a_n} =−\frac{F(x−an)−F(x)}{−a_n} $ converges towards $−f(x)$ and not $f(x)$! So my answer is also incomplete for now. Moreover, the constant $C$ you used is actually a $C_n$, it's dependent on $n$, so you can't do anything with it yet! (Deleted my answer for now until I find a way to recycle it into a correct solution)

Comment: There seems to be a method involving distributions for this kind of equations, but frankly I do not yet understand all the arguments, posting the link [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/440179/a-functional-equation) just in case though.

Comment: If I'm understanding things correctly, which I probably am not at all, the Fourier transform/distribution argument in the MathOverflow link I posted above should be usable to show that the only locally integrable solutions are polynomials (and then checking which polynomials are solutions should be easy), but this might not even cover all of our $f$s huh... Hopefully someone else finds a way. I guess I could write a partial solution showing the only $L^1$ solution is the zero function, but only if you judge it useful enough?