# Finding functions that satisfy a condition

Tags: real-analysis, limits, indefinite-integrals

Let $(a_n)_n$ be a positive numbers sequence such that$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} a_n =0 $$
Find the functions $f :R \to R$ that admit primitives such that $$2f(x)=f(x+a_n)+f(x-a_n)$$ for every x $\in R$ and n $\in N$
I've been struggling for a while with this problem. I've noticed that the linear functions satisfy the conditions but I don't know how I might prove that there aren't other functions. My instinct was to first prove that $f$ is monotonous, since  the existence of primitives ensures that the function has Darboux, but I didn't have any success.

Comment: Is the sequence $(a_n)$ arbitrary, i.e. must the relation hold for any such sequence? Or is $(a_n)$ a specific given sequence?

Comment: The sequence is arbitrary. @PierreCarre

Comment: Is $(a_n)$ arbitrary and fixed or just arbitrary? So do we want to find $f$ that fulfill the property for any given sequence $(a_n)$?

Comment: Sorry, $(a_n)$ is arbitrary and fixed.

Comment: This would be equivalent to $2f(x)=f(x+h)+f(x-h)$ for every $x,h\in\Bbb R.$ Is it really that what you want?

Comment: No, $(a_n)$ is fixed. Sorry,my bad.

Comment: Seems like the same question was asked before: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4634456/1104384

Comment: I didn't know. Probably the person who asked it before has the problem from the same source.